# Applying VBA function to matrix/array of data

Tags: vba, foreach, matrix-multiplication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUAh3.png)My result matrix from multiplication is a 3x1. I would like to apply my VBA  defined function to result matrix, h, and make a new matrix, h1. Any suggestion to improve this code? would a for each be better in the scenario?

Thanks Frens

```
Function sigmoid(X As Double) As Double
sigmoid = 1 / (1 + Exp(-X))
End Function

Sub arraymult()
    Dim i(0 To 2, 0 To 0) As Double
    Dim w(0 To 1, 0 To 2) As Double

i(0, 0) = 1
i(1, 0) = 2
i(2, 0) = 6

w(0, 0) = 2
w(0, 1) = 1
w(0, 2) = 1
w(1, 0) = 1
w(1, 1) = 1
w(1, 2) = 1

h = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(w, i)

        For j = 0 To 2
            h1(0, j) = sigmoid(h(0, j)) 'problem here
        Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: "result matrix from multiplication is a 3x1." - really?

Comment: i(3x1)* w(2x3)=h(3x1)

Comment: shouldn't it be = h(3x3)?

Comment: 2x1, my mistake

Comment: OK so in light of that change and what you can see in the locals window you need to change your `j` loop.

Comment: ok, but that isn't the issue. my issue is using sigmoid(h)

Comment: change `For j = 0 To 2` to `For j = Lbound(h,1) to Ubound(h,1)` and `h1(0, j) = sigmoid(h(j, 1))`  You also need to declare `h1`: `Dim h1() as variant` and Redim h1(0 to 0, lbound(h,1) to Ubound(h,1))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare you arrays as variant then use Cdbl to make it a double when passing to the function.

```
Function sigmoid(X As Double) As Double
    sigmoid = 1 / (1 + Exp(-X))
End Function

Sub arraymult()
    Dim i(0 To 2, 0 To 0) As Double
    Dim w(0 To 1, 0 To 2) As Double


    i(0, 0) = 1
    i(1, 0) = 2
    i(2, 0) = 6

    w(0, 0) = 2
    w(0, 1) = 1
    w(0, 2) = 1
    w(1, 0) = 1
    w(1, 1) = 1
    w(1, 2) = 1

    Dim h() As Variant
    h = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(w, i)

    Dim h1() As Variant
    ReDim h1(0 To 0, LBound(h, 1) To UBound(h, 1))

    For j = LBound(h, 1) To UBound(h, 1)
        h1(0, j) = sigmoid(CDbl(h(j, 1))) 'problem here
    Next j


End Sub
```

[image]